# Accessing PHP objects using both naming with reserved characters (-,@) and indexes (0)

Tags: php, object, character, json, reserved

In PHP figured out how to use {name-with-reserved-chars} notation to access object data after JSON decode but I also have index values as well in the path (like [0]).  My attempts to add the index value has returned nothing despite all my attempts to vary the pattern.  Here is an example based on a big JSON object:

```
["ops:world-patent-data"]["exchange-documents"]["exchange-document"]
[0]["bibliographic-data"]["publication-reference"]["document-id"][0].date.$
```

my attempt gets nothing:

```
print $result->{'ops:world-patent-data'}->{'exchange-documents'}->{'exchange-document'}->
      {0}->{'bibliographic-data'}->{'publication-reference'}->{'document-id'}->{0}->date;
```

wondering how to place the 0 and 1 indexes in the path ...

Comment: You probably want `[0]`, note the square braces instead of curly `{0}`.

Comment: Or even simpler, use `json_decode($in, TRUE)` to get a plain array without mixed objects and lists.

Comment: @mario - Only simpler if you point out the square bracket notation needed for all keys and numeric indexes (unless I'm wrong...?). (And I think *easier* is in the eye of the beholder. Why is it easier?)

Comment: @JaredFarrish True. To me it's simpler to traverse anyway if it's a coherent hash. The `{'..'}` complex string syntax is sometimes prettier, but often feels like a workaround. -- To OP: You might wish to paste your JSON into http://array.include-once.org/ to see how to access nodes either way.

Comment: @mario - I agree in general, just wanted to make sure the OP understood what was being proposed as well what was actually wrong with what was given.

Answer (score 3):

When deserializing an actual JSON **list** (i.e, not an object but an actual array with numerical indices; something like `[1,2,3,...]` or also `[{...},{...},...]`), PHP's `parse_json` function builds a corresponding PHP array with numerical indices (while on the other hands, it maps JSON **objects** to instances of the `stdClass` class -- unless you use the `$assoc` parameter of the `parse_json` function).

So, because you are accessing arrays instead of objects, your code would probably have to look like this:

```
print $result->{'ops:world-patent-data'}->{'exchange-documents'}->
    {'exchange-document'}[0]->{'bibliographic-data'}->{'publication-reference'}->
    {'document-id'}[0]->date;
```

It would probably easier to use the `$assoc` parameter, forcing `json_decode` to map the entire JSON object with associative arrays, allowing you to use the square bracket notation for object access also.